# Why do we need node clusters if we can change the number of threads utilized by the threadpool?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, multiprocessing, libuv

The title basically says it all, why should we create node workers when we can just change the number of threads the libuv threadpool uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libuv` threadpool isn't used for your JavaScript code, and is only used for a subset of Node.js's APIs (though it's used by one of the most major ones, `fs`). From [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_uv_threadpool_size_size):

> Asynchronous system APIs are used by Node.js whenever possible, but where they do not exist, `libuv`'s threadpool is used to create asynchronous node APIs based on synchronous system APIs. Node.js APIs that use the threadpool are:
>
> - all `fs` APIs, other than the file watcher APIs and those that are explicitly synchronous
> - asynchronous crypto APIs such as `crypto.pbkdf2()`, `crypto.scrypt()`, `crypto.randomBytes()`, `crypto.randomFill()`, `crypto.generateKeyPair()`
> - `dns.lookup()`
> - all `zlib` APIs, other than those that are explicitly synchronous

So the size of the `libuv` threadpool helps with lots of overlapping `fs` and similar calls, but it's not the whole story.

The `libuv` pool doesn't help you if you have JavaScript code that needs to do substantial work synchronously; that code runs on a single thread (unless you spin up workers). Moreover, Node.js uses that same thread to check for completions of asynchronous work (including `libuv` completions). From the [event loop page](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/):

> The following diagram shows a simplified overview of the event loop's order of operations.
>
> ```
>    ┌───────────────────────────┐
> ┌─>│           timers          │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
> │  │     pending callbacks     │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
> │  │       idle, prepare       │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘      ┌───────────────┐
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐      │   incoming:   │
> │  │           poll            │<─────┤  connections, │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘      │   data, etc.  │
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐      └───────────────┘
> │  │           check           │
> │  └─────────────┬─────────────┘
> │  ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
> └──┤      close callbacks      │
>    └───────────────────────────┘
> ```

So that one thread is doing a lot of work even when not running your JavaScript code.

If you spin up worker threads, they each have their own event loop and can process completions related to their work even if another thread is busy doing something CPU-heavy.

So whether worker threads are useful in any given situation is highly dependent on what your code is doing.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I misunderstood how node deals with async operations, I thought all of them were offloaded by the eventloop to libuv's threadpool, but if that's not the case, where do these operations (like fetching info from db) get executed?

Comment: @ThabetSabha - They get *started* from the main thread using asynchronous APIs in the operating system that let that thread go on to do other things while the work is happening. Those asynchronous OS APIs provide a way to check on completion, which the thread does in-between calls to your JavaScript code. I'm not an expert on the Node.js event loop and I'm sure there's more subtlety to it than that, but that's the general idea they convey in the linked event loop page.

Comment: Awesome, I was confused about this for a while but this really helped clear things up, so again thank you!